# Unary union/Dissolve returns null geometry in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, dissolve

I am writing a python processing script in QGIS 3. In it, I have polygon geometry objects stored in a list `polygonGeoms` and I want to dissolve all of it into one geometry. However, when calling the function `QgsGeometry.unaryUnion(polygonGeoms)`, it returns a null geometry. I've used the `unaryUnion` function before so I know that it should give me the result I want.

To investigate, I exported the geometries as a temporary shapefile layer. And when I use the `Dissolve` tool in QGIS 3, it also returns a null feature. The `Dissolve` tool works on the shapefile when I use QGIS 2.18 though, for some reason.

[This is a link to the sample shapefile.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XdsIcVj2kBD7znnVoOfvwSlCFMls-pgj)

Answer (score 3):

I did not find any issue with your data. Unary union is working fine at my end

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
vl = iface.activeLayer()
geoms = [f.geometry() for f in vl.getFeatures()]
g = QgsGeometry.unaryUnion(geoms)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code as text to your answer?